# Fatal error: Exception code=C0000005 and VFP9

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, visual-foxpro, windows-xp-sp2

in one of our client system we are getting this error message, not allowing us to open application. & in the log file path :**Error log file: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VFP\vfp7rerr.log** i got the error message like **"statdesktop.tmrtimer.timer"**
& i'm new to this type of syntax & concept,please let me know the reason behind this error.

Comment: You'll find lots of ideas about this error at http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~c0000005Error~Wiki

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the source-code to the application?  It appears the error is a result of a timer object as so referenced per your post.  Look for that in the source code and see what it is trying to do.  It may be looking for an import file of some type to be processed and either does not exist, or may have bad data it is trying to process.  It could also be something like permissions to some path it is trying to work with.

So, without much more than what you provided, I can't offer more.  Maybe when you find the source code, you can update this existing question with more details and myself and others may follow-up with more.

Comment: Thank you @DRapp,Sorry i don't have source because buyed software from some IT company. & also this will work good in other machine but not in the one specific machine.

Answer (score 0):

The first step I use when diagnosing C0000005 problems is DEP. Older versions of Foxpro, like version 7, when using 3rd party libraries often have problems with DEP. There were a number of changes made in Foxpro 9 in [how memory is allocated for executing code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2005/11/09/491168.aspx) specifically to deal with this.

Make sure to [add the executable to the DEP exclusion list](http://antivirus.about.com/od/securitytips/ht/excludefromdep.htm) and try again.

Comment: i excluded application from DEP but still i'm getting same error